# Using RoBERTa-base for QA model outputs the context not an answer

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, roberta-language-model

I'm trying to use this model from [deepset/roberta-base-squad2](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2) to essentially go through a column of work related activities and have it answer the question what are the necessary skills for this job ? However the model is simply handing me back my context or my question+context. I'm not quite sure why it's doing that.

Here's what I'm running,

```
import pandas as pd
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering

# Your DataFrame loading code here
# df = pd.read_csv("your_data.csv")

def generate_skills(question, context):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("deepset/roberta-base-squad2")
    model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("deepset/roberta-base-squad2")

    inputs = tokenizer(question, context, return_tensors='pt')
    outputs = model(**inputs)

    start_scores = outputs.start_logits
    end_scores = outputs.end_logits

    start_index = torch.argmax(start_scores)
    end_index = torch.argmax(end_scores) + 1

    tokens = inputs['input_ids'][0][start_index:end_index]
    answer = tokenizer.decode(tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)

    return answer

def generate_skills_for_row(row):
    context = row['top_words']
    question = "What are the necessary skills a data scientist should have?"
    skills = generate_skills(question, context)
    return skills

# Create a new column 'skills' based on the 'top_words' column
df['skills'] = df.apply(generate_skills_for_row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you show us one of your contexts? I assume the text differs too much from the Wikipedia articles the model was trained on. The model you are using is not a foundation model and therefore utterly domain specific. Maybe you can try Llama or Flan?

Comment: @cronoik example context: machine learning, data analysis, etl process, design development, data warehouse
this will give an answer as such: machine learning, data analysis, etl process, design development, data warehouse

So it just repeats the context.

Comment: That is not a good example to prove my point since I would say returning the entire context is acceptable (!) in that case. What I was trying to say, is that the model was trained on data of Wikipedia articles and the context contained enough information to find an answer without having knowledge of the topic (please note that I simplify here). Your question and context pairs require far more knowledge of the topic compared to squad. in case all of your contexts are just a list of words, you could try a zeroshot model.

Comment: @Moe_blg I am struggling with the same issue, using pipeline *works* where as using ```model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("deepset/roberta-base-squad2")``` with the same question and context, returns just the the question and context back again. Did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think of this model as an extractive model (On the [models' page](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2) it states "Downstream-task: Extractive QA"). This means that it simply extracts the right answer from the context you give it. If the answer isn't available in the context, you'll get an empty result. Also, it generally only locates the answer in one place in the context. So, if the answer is spread over several places in the context, it will only give you part of the correct answer.

Also, this model will probably perform better if you tailor it to the specific task you're doing. Check out the [main model's page on HF](https://huggingface.co/roberta-base) they explicitely mention "You can use the raw model for masked language modeling, but it's mostly intended to be fine-tuned on a downstream task"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the official guides allude to extracting the response from the model. [source](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/tasks/question_answering)

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering
import torch

model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained("deepset/roberta-base-squad2")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("deepset/roberta-base-squad2")

question = "How many parameters does BLOOM support?"
context = "BLOOM has 176 billion parameters and can generate text in 46 languages natural languages and 13 programming languages."

inputs = tokenizer(question, context, return_tensors="pt")
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = model(**inputs)

answer_start_index = outputs.start_logits.argmax()
answer_end_index = outputs.end_logits.argmax()

answer_tokens = inputs.input_ids[0, answer_start_index : answer_end_index + 1]

print(tokenizer.decode(answer_tokens))
```

This returns *176 billion* which is correct based on the provided question/context.

When utilizing the provided code with different test cases involving questions and context, the output includes the question/context instead of the expected answer. Backtesting with the `pipeline()` function using the identical question/context yields a useful response that cannot be replicated with the provided code snippet.